# How can I use the higher APIs while we set the minimum API to 7

Tags: android, api

Android studio has many APIs. But some of them have been added from API 13 or API 17 or API 20 or the higher APIs. If I set the minimum API to the `7`, do I can not  use the higher APIs in my project and they can work in android 2.1 well? If the answer is yes, please explain that how can I do this?

Comment: You cannot use higher API while you have lower minSdk version than it.

Comment: Do you really need to support version 7? It's already pretty old and makes development a lot harder. API version 15/16 is pretty standard nowadays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

My advice is to set the TargetSdkVersion always to the latest api version available. The minSdkVersion depends on which platform you want to support at least. If you want to use the newer api calls in your methods, you can annotate them with

> @TargetApi(Build.version)

But note that these calls will ONLY work at devices with the same or higher api version (and you do need to check this yourself before calling such a method, otherwise the application will probably crash).

Note that for some API calls it is possible to use the android compatibility package (http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) that makes some newer calls/design library's available for older API's.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will answer some of your questions. In short, you need to decide what versions of the SDK you want to set `Target Framework`, `Minimum Android Version`, and `Target Android Version` for compile and runtime.

Then, in the code, you'll be able to do something like this to only use code depending on SDK Version:

```
if (Android.OS.Build.Version.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop) 
{
   // Do things the Lollipop way
}
else
{
    // Do things the pre-Lollipop way
}
```

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/understanding_android_api_levels/

Answer (score 1):

support libraries provide you the way to use newer API's with your past releases.But they come with limited set of functionalities.

```
http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html
```

different support libraries provide different [features](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html). Their backward support is generally referred by their suffix 
like for example v4 Support Library support features for UI, accessibility,content and App components till API version 4. Using support libraries is regarded as the best practice to extend feature support to previous versions. Support libraries like CardView and Design Support Library helps you extend Material design to your previous version. v7 mediarouter library provides great features of controlling the routing of media channels and streams from the current device to external screens, speakers, and other destination devices. Since these libraries have specific set of use cases. you can easily make these functionalities backward compatible but in case of API which are not provided by support libraries you would have to write methods according to your `Build.Version`

Comment: Thank you. but what is this? how can I use this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use high level APIs in low versions of android. It is straight-forward. Suppose somehow (which is not even possible) you were able to compile your project setting minimum to 7 and used some API that only belongs to some higher level, when you app would run on device and would try to execute the API, OS would find no function/API and your app would crashed.
One thing is that if the API has some back-support like we have in support-libraries, then definitely you can use them in your such apps. Hope it will clear your question.